# Android Maven Eclipse JUnit: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException when attempting to execute local tests

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, junit

I have created a Maven project in Eclipse for an Android application.

Sources are in src/main/java and (local) unit tests, which *do not use* any Android class directly, are in src/test/java.

The weird thing is that when I try to run such a simple test in a package in src/test/java, just through Eclipse -> Run As -> JUnit test:

```
package org.blacklight.android.flexibleprofiles.status.global;

import static org.junit.Assert.fail;

import org.junit.Test;

public class TestGlobalStatus {
    @Test
    public void testGlobalStatus() {
        fail("Not supported");
    }

}
```

What I get is a ClassNotFoundException, even if the class is actually there:

```
Class not found org.blacklight.android.flexibleprofiles.status.global.TestGlobalStatus
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.blacklight.android.flexibleprofiles.status.global.TestGlobalStatus
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClass(RemoteTestRunner.java:693)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.loadClasses(RemoteTestRunner.java:429)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

I do have JUnit 4 ticket in my project's Java Build Path, so I just can't realize what's going on here.

Comment: Is it in the "target" folder? Sometimes it has happened to me that the class was not there and jUnit could not find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue with the [Android Connector for Maven Eclipse](http://rgladwell.github.io/m2e-android/):

https://github.com/rgladwell/m2e-android/issues/154